# Datatables remove all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I use DataTables and Bootstrap gentelella. Datatables work fine when they have some records. When I open page with empty data in table and go to Create page and go back I see that DataTables do not work ok.

[image]

I use this code for init Datatable:

```js
$('#table-programm-station')
  .DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "/js/datatables/Russian.json"
    },
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
      "sRowSelect": "multi",
      //"aButtons": ["select_all", "select_none"]
    }
  });
```

If I remove `language` option it all work fine. Also I at first load language json and successfully parse it then assign it to language option and have the same result.

I don't get any errors in the console. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cdn `'//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Russian.json'`.

It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L054581n/)

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   language : {
      url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Russian.json'
   }
});
```

Comment: @MetalEvolutionStudio I have updated with jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/L054581n/

Comment: I found error. It was not cause in DataTable. The problem was in custom pagination plugin. In this plugin I added callback that save pagination page. If there are not data in the table and back to page with Datatable, the callback removes all rows, because it didn't know that data was deleted and I currently added new record. So before you want do something with your table, you should check for table that is to be empty. 
```
if (dataTable.count() > 0) {
          
  dataTable.page.len(table.pageInfo.length).draw();
          
  dataTable.page(table.page - 1).draw( 'page' );
}
```

Comment: @MetalEvolutionStudio did you check the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yes, I checked link it was not helped me. This is a big project so I'll give you an pageSwitcher example
https://jsfiddle.net/6k7n0def/

Comment: @MetalEvolutionStudio can add html into jsfiddle?